# JHipster first application

Tags: jhipster

I’m a complete JHipster beginner and I want to create my first own JHipster application, but I got a problem that I’m not able to solve.
Firstly, I generated my app with following settings:
-Monolithic application
then I chose a base name and  a default Java package of my app and HTTP Session Authentication.
Later, I chose following:
-SQL, MYSQL, MYSQL, Yes, with ehcache, Gradle, CSS preprocessor : Yes, Internationalization: Yes, Testing framework: Gatling

And to that moment everything looked fine , then I wanted to create my entity as follows:

Yo jhipster:entity activitylist
and I added three fields:
-activityname (String), acitivitydate (LocalDate) and rating (Integer) and then I added relationship with entity user, type: many to one.
Afterwards
I used yo jhipster:entity user and I added following fields: login(String), name(String), surname(String) and added relationship one to many with field user.

However, everytime when I tried to run it with docker I got compile Java Failure and following warnings:
warning: Unmapped target property: "authorities".
    UserDTO userToUserDTO(User user);
error: Unknown property "password" in return type.
    User userDTOToUser(UserDTO userDTO);

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Instead of saying how you wrote you code, it is much more concise to add a small block of code and refer to it.

Comment: Yes or you can show your entity definitions found in `.jhipster` folder

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your app is the name of your entity: user. 
You need to change the name of this entity because when You name it as following You create a new Java class : User, however JHipster has its own built-in User Java class which is located in src/main/java/domain folder.

This class has its own getter, setter methods and mapper which operation is affected when your entity „user" is created.

You can notice this fact in Your warnings when compiler informs You that it encountered unknown properties in Your return type in User userDTOToUser. I would strongly recommend You changing name of the user entity and everything else should work fine.